# Does Activity save its intent when it's destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

Imagine situation where an activity was started with an intent, after that a user opens another activity, then another activity again and so on. At a moment, the first activity gets destroyed due to lacking RAM. Can the first activity access to its initial intent after user navigated back to it? Is there a strictly determined behaviour for that?

Comment: The initial intent would be the default as defined in the Manifest.

Comment: Yes - Android should be keeping hold of the intent data so that the Activity can be recreated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some comment snippets taken from the [Android source](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java#995):

```
/**     
     * Information you can retrieve about a particular task that is currently
     * "running" in the system.  Note that a running task does not mean the
     * given task actually has a process it is actively running in; it simply
     * means that the user has gone to it and never closed it, but currently
     * the system may have killed its process and is only holding on to its
     * last state in order to restart it when the user returns.
     */
    public static class RunningTaskInfo ...
```

Note the last statement: **...is only holding on to its last state in order to restart it when the user returns**

```
         /**
         * The original Intent used to launch the task.  You can use this
         * Intent to re-launch the task (if it is no longer running) or bring
         * the current task to the front.
         */
         public Intent baseIntent;
```

From this it should be apparent that Android will hold on to the original Intent to restart the Activity as if it was never destroyed.

Comment: State the citation to the source where you found the comment.

Comment: @t0mm13b it's pretty simple to search the Android source - I've added the link anyway.

Comment: Thank you. It's very helpful. But it refers to switching a task, but an activity can be destroyed without switching task. However destroying an activity in the current task seems to be a subset of destroying it in a background task. Thanks